# Trigger a click event on page load using knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

How do I trigger a click event of a div on page load using knockoutJS?
I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.divClass').first().trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In your code how does knockout comes into the picture? Do you want to trigger a knoclick `click` binding handler?

Comment: I am very new to knockout.
I have image thumbnails displayed at first. Each thumbnail are bound with knockout click handler and loads larger image on click. What I need is for the first thumbnail to be clicked by default on page load.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of MVVM is to seperate the View and the view logic (ViewModel). Instead of trigger the click trigger the function on the view model that is bound to the click

Comment: But the thing is that the click event passes the values of the data bound. 
`data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data)"`
This is a very imp part of my code.
How can I do that if I trigger the function instead?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I trigger a function on page load in knockout. Does not necessarily have to trigger a click event.

Comment: Show us your viewmodel please